# Create CSS buttons with equal padding

Tags: css, button, input, anchor

I am use the following css to create buttons

```
.cssButton {
background-color:#333333;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
display:inline-block;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

When applied to anchor links and inputs, I get different heights. Is there a way to force the properties to match in both elements?

Thanks

Comment: keep height and width in your css, I attached answer also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by setting a default `font-size` and `padding`.

```
.cssButton {
    background-color:#333333;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

[Also check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/DEe6F/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

add `padding:5px;` in below class :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CxvE8/1/)**

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.cssButton {
background-color:#333333;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
display:inline-block;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS Padding property

{

padding:5px

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.cssButton {
    background-color:#333333;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
```

you didn't keep height, width in your css. gud luck

Comment: if necessary then you can also attach 'float:left; '

Comment: This, along with `line-height:30px;` is the best solution. You also wouldn't need `float:left;` since it's inline-block.